# Creating custom class code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I code java in eclipse, and i am spending time every new problem i write the same starting code. So i wanted to create this as my custom class code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CLASSNAME {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

}

}
```

So i set my Preferences-Code templets-class body to that, but when i create a class i get this:

```
public class CLASSNAME {
import java.util.*;

public class CLASSNAME {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

}

}}
```

How do i stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `import java.util.*;` in "New Java files" instead of "Class body"?

Comment: New java files adds code to the bottom, not the top. I get this

{

public class Test2 {
 public class Test2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  }

 }
}

'import.java.util.*;'

}